# Apache POI Generate Report

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am currently working on a Java software project aimed at generating reports. Within the Excel file (xlsx) used in this project, there exist two distinct worksheets: 'Report' and 'DB'.

The 'DB' worksheet houses values retrieved from a database through the utilization of an XLA extension, employing the formula =AimHistValue(P1, P2, P3, P4). This formula yields the expected result of 1.92.

In the 'Report' worksheet, there exists an association linking to 'DB!E33'.

The software functions flawlessly on the host machine where the database resides. However, there arises a need to transfer these files to alternate machines for further processing.

Regrettably, during the file transfer process, all contents within the .xlsx file are inadvertently lost. I have made attempts to employ an evaluator but have encountered challenges as it struggles to process the formula =AimHistValue.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure the successful execution of the software on different machines without data loss.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellValue;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;

// ... (Altre importazioni necessarie)

private void copyFormulasAsValues(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet reportSheet) {
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    for (Row row : reportSheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                CellValue formulaResult = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
                if (formulaResult.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    double value = formulaResult.getNumberValue();
                    // Imposta il risultato numerico come valore nella stessa cella
                    cell.setCellValue(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Esempio di utilizzo
private void generateReport() {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\percorso\\del\\tuo\\file.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet reportSheet = workbook.getSheet("Report");

        copyFormulasAsValues(workbook, reportSheet);

        // ... (Altre operazioni o salvataggio del file)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be a solution to save the file in csv and convert it back to excel and compare the values ​​containing formulas with the new excel file?

Comment: You seem to have read the file using `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(...)`, but it seems you haven't written it back to the disk after converting all the formulae to values.

Comment: Ignore..  Just translated "Altre operazioni o salvataggio del file"..  So, I hope the file is written back to the disk.  And after that, have you tried to open it in your own machine and check that all the formulae have been converted to values?

Comment: Can you also try and delete the 'DB' sheet as part of the save process?  Keep it in the original, but not the one saved with fixed values.  This is to make sure that on the destination server, the DB sheet does not try to regenerate the values in the Report sheet.

Comment: Yes, the sent file is just a small excerpt. I have read that for custom formulas it is necessary to write the functioning of the formula because it is not recognized. I tried to delete the DB sheet but the result is the same

Comment: What I think is you need to first copy the DB Worksheet and then the Report Worksheet. As the Report Worksheet is using data evaluated from the other worksheet. May be it is unable to locate DB (technically, which also does not exist yet), therefore not able to intercept what the cell E33 from DB worksheet contains etc?

Comment: In reality, when debugging, the value is not present in the cell, it is probably the fault of the extension, apachePOI opens the file in XML and the extension is not processed, it is processed as soon as Excel is opened...